# My program is not outputting anything from the file :/

Tags: c++, input, ofstream

I am doing the following exercise:

[image]

My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    double currentSalary, increaseRate, updatedSalary;
    string firstName, lastName;

    inFile.open ("Data.txt");
    outFile.open("Output.dat");
    outFile << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    inFile >> lastName >> firstName;
    inFile >> currentSalary >> increaseRate;
    updatedSalary = currentSalary * (1 + increaseRate / 100);
    outFile << firstName << " " << lastName<< " " << updatedSalary << endl;
    inFile >> lastName >> firstName;
    inFile >> currentSalary >> increaseRate;
    updatedSalary = currentSalary * (1 + increaseRate / 100);

    outFile << firstName << " " << lastName<< " " << updatedSalary << endl;
    inFile >> lastName >> firstName;
    inFile >> currentSalary >> increaseRate;
    updatedSalary = currentSalary * (1 + increaseRate / 100);
    outFile << firstName << " " << lastName<< " " << updatedSalary << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I debug it with MS VS.. it just says "press any key to continue..."

Where do I add the Data.txt file?

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Is it writing out `output.dat`?  There is no reason to use `pause` if you are not printing to the screen.

Comment: Bought exercise and code in-situ so as to remove dependencies on external sites.

Comment: Do you have a `data.txt` file?  Do you know what the current directory is when you run the program?  You can do `system("CHDIR");` to see it, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, given that you don't output anything to the screen, I'm not at all surprised that's all you see.

If I were you, I'd have a look at the `Output.dat` file to see if it's writing anything.

If you're seeing nothing in that file, then it's probably because you don't have your `Data.txt` file in the directory where you're running. With VS, this is usually under the `bin` or `debug` directory somewhere inside your solution directory.

You can find out which directory that is by putting `system("cd");` at the start of your code and running it.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. I was freaking out then realized I'm not outputting anything to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the Data.txt at the same directory where you will execute the binary file or put the absolute path of Data.txt, like `inFile.open ("C:\Documents\Data.txt")`, otherwise will never be found.